# Oldest appearance of "brand names" in history?

Tags: ancient-history, economy

I was watching a documentary about the Ulfberht swords from Scandinavia, and one thing caught my attention: it mentioned that these swords were made over a range of time and location that was broad enough that they couldn't have been made by the same craftsman.  That "Ulfberht" name, even if it started as a craftsman's mark, became simply a name for a sword of that particular style, design and quality.  Effectively, it became a brand.

That made me wonder: when was the first appearance of "brand names" for products?  (For the purposes of this discussion, we can define a "brand name" as an abstract label associated with a particular product and/or production facility, but not with any particular person or simple descriptor.  So, not a "Da Vinci painting" or "Italian marble," but something equivalent to a "Nike shoe," where designers can come and go but the name retains its continuity.)

Were there product lines, like swords or dresses or furniture, in Ancient Rome that were known by name, independent of their maker?  In China, or Medieval Europe?  When did a product first become detached from its maker in the minds of the consumers?

Comment: Nice question, but where would you place Ford, Gucci, Ferrari etc?

Comment: I would argue that those are still brands, at least for the purposes of this question, because they aren't actually made BY those people.  The person began the organization and then named it after themselves, but no one labors under the misunderstanding that Henry Ford personally made their car, the way "a Da Vinci painting" implies that it was personally painted by Da Vinci.

Comment: Do you care whether the answer is a brand that still exists? E.g. Ulfberht doesn't, Champagne does.

Comment: I think your definition of a brand is very vague and impractical. Why do Swiss cheese qualify if Italian marble not? Are you talking about brands that are intentionally created, or by chance (simple geographic names, like Champagne)? Why Michelangelo is not a brand if much of his works was helped/created by his assistants (not a one man show)?

Comment: There is a confused premise to this question that leads to the widely divergent answers here. Brands exist to differentiate otherwise similar products ("Converse sneakers are completely different than Nike sneakers!") and to instill loyalty in customers to a particular producer, on the assumption that the qualities of one product line transfer to the next product line ("I like iPods so I will like iPads"). Ulfbehrt swords and Damascus steel collapse these distinctions. Subsuming multiple swords under one title "undifferentiates" products and makes consumers less loyal to particular producers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Damascus steel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damascus_steel), I think, should qualify: it's a product which was recognized by name regardless of the actual manufacturer.  It is now *defunct* in the sense that the technology has been lost.

Many other interesting products qualify, from wines ([Burgundy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burgundy_wine) and [Champagne](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champagne_%28wine%29)) to cheeses ([Swiss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss_cheese) and [Dutch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Dutch_cheeses)). These are *active* in the sense that one cannot sell a wine and call it "Burgundy" unless it satisfies certain strict conditions.

Other product names became generic (e.g., [china](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porcelain)).

Comment: Were any of those products made by a specific organization, though?  Being named after a location makes it sound less like saying "a Lexus car" and more like saying "an Italian car."  More of a description than an actual brand.  Or was Damascus steel only made by a certain foundry or workshop?  Either way, a very interesting and helpful answer!

Comment: @AlexanderWinn: any product was invented by someone, but the names of the ancient inventors have been lost. Regardless of what these names _look_ like, they are certainly _brands_ in the sense that they have certain  recognizable desirable properties which distinguish them from alternatives.

Comment: Damascus Steel is a process more than a brand.  Once learned, anyone could make it.  The Romans used to stamp tiles with the name of the place that made them.

Comment: Don't mix up trade marks and protected designations of origins with brands.

Answer (score 4):

On archaeology shows I have heard of tiles being marked with the maker's sign that can be used to find out where the tiles were made even now.  So trademarks and brand signs if not names have a very old lineage.

> Stone seals dating to 3,500 B.C. have been found in the Middle East.
>   The seals were used to indicate who made certain items. The ancient
>   Egyptians, Greeks, Romans, and Chinese all used various forms of
>   stamps or markings to indicate who made certain things, such as
>   pottery or bricks. Not only did the marks indicate quality, but they
>   also let people know whom to blame if there was a problem with the
>   product.

[Source](http://www.infoplease.com/spot/trademarks1.html)

Answer (score 1):

The modern share-capital corporation only arises in the 1600's, with the Dutch East India company I believe. Prior to then, *by definition*, everything is a proprietorship or a partnership.

Earlier adoption of any concept similar to a share-capital corporation I believe to be impossible, as the accounting and bookkeeping concepts had not yet been developed to support its paperwork.

Further, I believe that the definition of *brand* given by OP must be strengthened slightly in order to be meaningful; namely of being *protected under law*, and not just a manufacturing technique. Under this my belief is the *Ulfberht* would not qualify, though perhaps someone else can do the research to settle this point..

Therefore I believe the logo and brand of the [Dutch East India Trading Company](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_East_India_Company), established 1602, meets the criteria as the oldest *brand* not associated with an individual or partnership.

**Update**:
Clarification - I am not claiming that only a share-capital corporation can own a brand - only that only a share-capital corporation can exist for long enough to meet OP's designation of the **type of brand** that OP is inquiring about - one that lasted for a period significantly longer than a single lifetime, and perhaps for much longer.

Comment: +1 for that answer. I wondered if this is also the first instance of a "company" in whatever form. Is there any interesting references/books about this?

Comment: You fail to explain why only a share-capital corporation would be able to own a brand, i don't see why a person or a family could own one. Also, there are examples of share-capital corporations before the 1600's. Cicero participated in an organization in which he provided money, while others provided boats, mules or manpower to pull of large trading voyages (senators where not allowed to own large vessels). such organizations where often temporary, but at times stayed together.

Comment: Also the VOC did not sell a product that was exclusively associated with their brand as a sign of quality, so i don't think it's what OP is looking for.

Comment: @JeroenK: I believe you are confusing a partnership with a share-capital corporation. Partnerships certainly have existed for ages, but they dissolve and reform on every arrival, death or departure of a partner. As such, they cannot exist for longer than a single lifetime. What you describe for Cicero, from your description, was most definitely a partnership.

Comment: @Rajib: To the best of my knowledge and research, *The Dutch East India Trading Company* is the oldest known example of a share-capital corporation. I believe the oldest still in operation is *The Hudson's Bay Trading Company*, now operating in Canada simply under the name *The Bay*.

Comment: I suppose you're right, cicero's corporation must have been a partnership. But why would only a share capital corporation be able to own a brand?

Comment: @JeroenK: Because a partnership doesn't, and can't, own anything. A partnership is simply a contractual agreement on how the partners share use and profits of assets.

Comment: +1 for sticking to the question. As Jeroen K points, an individual or family can own a brand, but the question specifically asks for brands not related to individuals, and that can only be owned by some kind of companies. However, I agree that some kind of companies existed in ancient and medieval times and they could be a better answer if an example of them owning some kind of brand was to be found.

Comment: @Pere: Have you any legal or accounting training that might include the key concept of "incorporation" - the process of creating a "body" unassociated with a living breathing person?